# How can I improve the design of the 'Show Phone Contacts' dialog in my app?

Tags: critique, mobile, android, button

[image]

In the add contact dialog, I am suppose to add a button/link that will take the user to a view that shows the saved phone contacts.

I know that the `Show Phone Contacts >>` view pretty much sucks here for my required purpose but I have no idea what else to do with it.

Comment: Hi Smrita, welcome to GD SE! I've given a general answer, but we really need to know what your current issue is with this design element. I personally don't see anything wrong with it. Please give us more information about what's good or bad about it, and why you want to change it.

Comment: I know nothing on graphic design in general and I can't comment on that, but I know if I was using this application on my Android phone those two '>' symbols at the end would really throw me off. I would suggest removing them, but on the other hand I know nothing about graphic design...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're only problem with it is that it's a bit boring, that's not a very important problem. Often boring elements aren't so boring as part of the finished design.

I personally can't see anything wrong with it; it's different enough that it stands out from the other elements, and it invites interaction thanks to those arrows.

Anyway, if you really want to add some visual interest, I suggest using some variation of the icon that used to be used for MSN Messenger and similar programs:

[image][image]

<sup>Click messenger image to go to source website</sup>

Comment: Yes I meant that its simple and has no style ( basically I mean that its boring) :). Thank you so much . You exactly addressed my problem:).

Comment: Glad I could help :)